# center of mass system, momentum

Tags: syntax, physics

1. when I have  systems with 3 mass points ($m_i, i=1,2,3$) to a time $t=t_0$ on positions $\vec r_i(t_0)$ and velocity $\vec v_i(t_0)$. How could a syntax look like to calculate

1) center of mass
2) total momentum
3) total angular momentum

for any number of mass points?

2. Secondly, later when time is $t_1 > t_0$ the positions and velocities of 2 of this 3 mass poins are known. How could mathematica calculate position and velocity of third mass point, when there is no external force ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Center of mass:

```
Total[m1 r1, m2 r2, m3 r3]/Total[m1,m2,m3]
```

Total momentum:

```
Total[m1 v1, m2 v2, m3 v3]
```

Total angular momentum:

```
Total[m1 Cross[r1,v1], m2 Cross[r2,v2], m3 Cross[r3,v3]]
```

Comment: thanx so far david!