# center of mass, total momentum

Tags: syntax, physics

Has someone an idea how to solve the 1. question for ANY number of mass points and a clue to the 2. question?

[center of mass system, momentum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/center-of-mass-system-momentum)

Comment: Didn't you tell me to do it like this in main question??

Comment: Yes, but I didn't mean something like the above which just references the previous question. I meant a fully written out question with the full problem statement so the new question can stand alone.

Comment: @Tom Indeed, a bit more self-containedness of this question would be desirable. When I read it the first time I thought "What the ... do they mean with '1. question'?"

Comment: ok, in future I will try to do it more correctly! thank you for patience !

Comment: Near duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/center-of-mass-system-momentum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for many particles are best stored in arrays.

```
n = 10000;
masses = RandomReal[{0.1, 1.}, {n}];
positions = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
velocities = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
```

Now, one obtains

```
centerofmass = masses.positions;
momenta = masses velocities;
totalmomentum = masses.velocities;
angularmomenta = MapThread[Cross, {positions, momenta}];
totalangularmomentum = Total[angularmomenta];
```

## Performance Tuning

There is an issue with `Cross`: For some reason, it is way slower than it should be. Here is a compiled, listable, and parallelized version of it for 3-vectors:

```
cross = With[{
   code = Cross[
     Table[Compile`GetElement[X, i], {i, 1, 3}],
     Table[Compile`GetElement[Y, i], {i, 1, 3}]
     ]
   },
  Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {Y, _Real, 1}},
   code,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ]
  ]
```

It is about 500 times faster than `Cross` on my machine and it is already `Listable` so that we don't need `MapThread`:

```
angularmomenta2 = cross[positions, momenta];
```

Up to machine precision, the result is the same:

```
Max[Abs[angularmomenta - angularmomenta2]]
```

> 2.22045*10^-16

Comment: you´re genious Henrik! thank you!

Comment: Huh, thanks for the flowers. You're welcome.